# Pyvirtualdisplay doesn't like text

Tags: python, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay

I want to get some text from a web page with `selenium` but when I use the `pyvirtualdisplay` package and I write code like this:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display 
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
...
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('...').text
print elem
...
```

it prints an empty string. If I don't use `pyvirtualdisplay`, doing the same things, it works fine and displays the right string.
Why does this happen and how can I solve?

Comment: What browser are you using? Is this not a headless environment?

Comment: I solved using chrome instead of firefox... I don't know why but today firefox (with selenium) stopped working: when I use browser.get('url') it open a firefox windows but doesn't run the URL. Any explanation?